# Hiding .env on a public server

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have a node.js project that uses dotenv for secrets (API keys, db config/login/pass).

I didn't think about this when I was building it, but it needs to be hosted on my school's engineering server for grading and sharing with classmates instead of on Heroku where I would usually host.

If it were Heroku, I could store the env variables there no problem, but on my school server, the .env file will just be out there to everyone.

So my question is: Is there a way to host on a public server without exposing the .env file?

Comment: You could encode  your env variables and you can decode them while you are using in your app ,as I don't see any other way to hide it if its open .

Comment: That's an interesting idea. A layer of obfuscation (and MFA on the accounts) might be just enough to help me sleep at night for the 3 weeks that it will be live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are serveral choices:

- [GCP secret manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager)
- [AWS secret manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)
- [vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault)
- [kubernetes ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/), [kubernetes Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

You can even store it in the database, read the configs and secrets at application runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically create a folder with only read access from the service user that is running the project.
Or atleast something in that direction.

Comment: Well there is something called root access or sudo

Comment: So it's not your school server, it's a shared one?

Comment: The school manages the server and makes it available for student use.